# Set thread affinity on two cores using OpenMP

Tags: c, multithreading, gcc, openmp, affinity

I am using a C program, compiled with gcc 4.9.2 on Windows7, using OpenMP 4.0.
My computer is dual core, with four threads.
I'd like to use thread affinity spread and use 2 threads put on different cores. So when I set the environment variables from DOS with:

> - set OMP_NUM_THREADS=2
> - set OMP_PROC_BIND=spread
> - set OMP_PLACES="cores"

I get, with the variable OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=true, this:

```
libgomp: Invalid value for environment variable OMP_PLACES

OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT BEGIN
  _OPENMP = '201307'
  OMP_DYNAMIC = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NESTED = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NUM_THREADS = '2'
  OMP_SCHEDULE = 'DYNAMIC'
  OMP_PROC_BIND = 'SPREAD'
  OMP_PLACES = ''
  OMP_STACKSIZE = '12872703'
  OMP_WAIT_POLICY = 'PASSIVE'
  OMP_THREAD_LIMIT = '4294967295'
  OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS = '2147483647'
  OMP_CANCELLATION = 'FALSE'
  OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE = '0'
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT END
```

It seems that the input is not valid, so I changed it to:

> - set OMP_PLACES="cores"

```
  libgomp: Affinity not supported on this configuration 
  OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT BEGIN
  _OPENMP = '201307'
  OMP_DYNAMIC = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NESTED = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NUM_THREADS = '2'
  OMP_SCHEDULE = 'DYNAMIC'
  OMP_PROC_BIND = 'SPREAD'
  OMP_PLACES = ''
  OMP_STACKSIZE = '3107827'
  OMP_WAIT_POLICY = 'PASSIVE'
  OMP_THREAD_LIMIT = '4294967295'
  OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS = '2147483647'
  OMP_CANCELLATION = 'FALSE'
  OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE = '0'
  OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT END
```

And this is the result: affinity not supported. I get the same result even with:

> set OMP_PLACES="{0},{2},{1},{3}"

Does any of you know how to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried a simple hello world code compiled with gcc 4.9.3 on Linux, with the environment variables you proposed:

```
~/tmp$ OMP_DISPLAY_ENV=true OMP_NUM_THREADS=2 OMP_PROC_BIND=spread OMP_PLACES=cores ./a.out 

OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT BEGIN
  _OPENMP = '201307'
  OMP_DYNAMIC = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NESTED = 'FALSE'
  OMP_NUM_THREADS = '2'
  OMP_SCHEDULE = 'DYNAMIC'
  OMP_PROC_BIND = 'SPREAD'
  OMP_PLACES = '{0:2},{2:2}'
  OMP_STACKSIZE = '140736864318339'
  OMP_WAIT_POLICY = 'PASSIVE'
  OMP_THREAD_LIMIT = '4294967295'
  OMP_MAX_ACTIVE_LEVELS = '2147483647'
  OMP_CANCELLATION = 'FALSE'
  OMP_DEFAULT_DEVICE = '0'
OPENMP DISPLAY ENVIRONMENT END
Hello from thread 0 / 2
Hello from thread 1 / 2
```

So basically, it works for me, and I believe that what you tried is legit. However, the message you get `Affinity not supported on this configuration` let me believe that affinity might simply not be available on your Windows 7 machine. I have no such environment to test, but the OpenMP standard says that:

> The determination of whether the affinity request can be fulfilled is
>   implementation defined. If the affinity request cannot be fulfilled,
>   then the affinity of threads in the team is implementation defined.

I guess that's were we are...

Comment: Hi Gilles. I had it tested on Ubuntu with the same configuration and I agree with you. Unfortunately, I have to use Win7 for my application, and I want to discover if there are any differences using OpenMP between gcc version 4.9.2 and version 4.9.3. I will let you know.

Comment: Hi again Gilles. I tested my application on Windows7 using gcc version 5.1 getting the same result. So I'd finally say that OpenMP thread affinity is not supported on Windows 7 machines.